# How to use git checkouts without requiring rebuilds with make

Tags: git, makefile

Since I started working with git, I have picked up the habit of storing executables of other branches and tags. The reason is that I do not want the bother of checking out the branch, building the executable, and then be forced to check out my working branch and rebuild everything. This can take quite some time on large repos (10 min on my current project).

Problems can happen when there are other version controlled files that interact with my binary. My current example are openGL shaders, that are read and compiled run-time. Even though I have the binary from the branch in question, execution will be wrong, because my shader files have changed.

Solution 1: checkout the original branch as that would change the shader files.

- Requires a commit or a stashing on my working branch.
- When i switch back to my working branch, all my files in the repo have been modified, so calling **make** forces a full rebuild.

Solution 2: checkout only the shader files from the branch in question, and then run the executable.

- Requires a commit or a stashing on my working branch.
- High risk of forgetting the files that have been checked out manually. I have to keep track of them myself, make sure I revert on my working branch before continuing work.

Solution 3: make a clone of the repo, just to keep the executable for that specific branch.

- each clone will take up space (15 GB in my case).
- will have to manage all those repos when the individual branches are updated

All of this would be avoided, if **make** worked differently. If some kind of hasch description of the files were used instead of the operating systems time-stamps. However, when you copy files, there are ways to do so while keeping the "modified date". I am wondering if I could do that with git. If so, I could checkout the branch, run the executable, and then checkout my working branch once again, without invalidating all the files in my repo, and thus **make** would not trigger a full rebuild

Comment: Couldn't you use two clones, a fetch-only one to fetch and run your executables, and a fetch-and-push one for your development work?

Comment: The immediate answer to this is to use Git worktrees.  They're vastly superior to using multiple clones.  At any given time I have between 5 and 20 worktrees for my work projects.

Comment: @MadScientists (and Renaud), thanks for feedback. The git worktree option seems strange to me, especially since it does not support submodules. Seems like more complexity to my git useage, with little extra benefit. I get that I will have copies without copying the full .git DB, but for my use-case extra clones (with shallow depth) would give the same functionality with no more commands to keep track off. Or am I missing something